# PHP MYSQL Duplicate rows filter

Tags: php, mysql

I want find duplicate records in table

> table_name: billing
>   there are 7 cols, but I am intrested in only 3 cols values.

I want find rows, where 3 cols (suite, comment, amount) values are similar

For example:

```
suite comment amount other col
11     44      0.00    88
11     44      0.00    33
17     48      1.00    11
17     48      1.00    35
17     48      1.00    21
```

Comment: Tell us about `other col`

Answer (score 0):

Not particularly efficient, but if you don't need to do this quickly.

```
 Select b.* from
 (SELECT 
     Suite, comment, amount
 FROM
     YourTable
 GROUP BY
     Suite, comment, amount
 Having count(1) > 1) a
 Inner join
 YourTable b
 On a.suite = b.suite and a.comment = b.comment and a.amount = b.amount
```